# Allow duplicates selection in select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I would like to allow multiple select of a same value as shown here : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/qcgvucnz/1/ (tried with select2-3.5) but I'm with select2-4.0. Since I'm using Laravel Voyager, I can't change the version.

Currently, the multi-select is working as in here : https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

I don't really know how to achieve that and I already went to all the github to find some solution with no result

I tried some things on this event specifically : 
but it did nothing

```
        $(this).on('select2:select',function(e){
            var data = e.params.data;
            $(e.currentTarget).find("option[value='" + data.id + "']").attr('selected','selected');;
        });
```

Did someone already achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want that? keep in mind that the jsfiddle let's you add the same option multiple times but the actual value of the select won't have the repeated value (check `document.querySelector('select.select2').value`).

Comment: I want to allow multiple select for a same tag because of this : I have a piece of cloth that can have multiple attributes for example two sleeves. I want to achieve that in specific cases

Comment: I don't think allowing multiple selections of the same option on the select2 plugin will help you with that. When you submit the form the option will appear only once since options can't be selected twice in a real html select input.

Comment: I see, that would be bad... Would you maybe have an idea on how I should do that then? The result would be something like this ```cloth: {attributes:[1,1,4,5]}``` assuming that 1 is for sleeves, 4 is for collar etc...

Comment: You could have a text input (instead of a select) and use a tokenizer plugin (instad of a select plugin) to populate the input with an array of values. Check this for example http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/, if you add the same token twice and inspect `document.querySelector('#tokeninput-demo').value` you'll see the the value twice separated by a comma. Then you'll have to handle that on the controller manually, you'll have a string "1,1,4,5", you need to split that and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure this out the other day.

```
$(this).on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
    //console.log("UNSELECT");
    //console.log(e);
    if (e.params.originalEvent != null && e.params.originalEvent.handleObj.type == "mouseup") {
        $(this).append('<option value="' + e.params.data.id + '">' + e.params.data.text + '</option>');
        let vals = $(this).val();
        vals.push(e.params.data.id);
        $(this).val(vals).trigger('change');
        $(this).select2('close');
    } else if (e.params.data.element != null) {
        e.params.data.element.remove();
    }
});
```

I found that (in Select2 4.1.0) when you re-select a value it calls the 'unselect' event instead of the 'select' event. Additionally, the trigger for that event is always 'mouseup' when selecting in this manner and 'click' when you actually click the button to remove the selected object.

You need to add the option to the select element and then tell Select2 to pick that value (again) and trigger a change event.

You can take it one step further if you want maximum efficiency by using the 'unselecting' event as well.

```
$(this).on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {
    //console.log("PREUNSELECT");
    //console.log(e);
    if (e.params.args.originalEvent != null && e.params.args.originalEvent.handleObj.type == "mouseup") {
        $(this).append('<option value="' + e.params.args.data.id + '">' + e.params.args.data.text + '</option>');
        let vals = $(this).val();
        vals.push(e.params.args.data.id);
        $(this).val(vals).trigger('change');
        $(this).select2('close');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
$(this).on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
    //console.log("UNSELECT");
    //console.log(e);
    if (e.params.data.element != null) {
        e.params.data.element.remove();
    }
});
```